# What happens have you create an object with a name already used before in python?

Tags: python

I am creating objects in a loop and I have no use of them after the loop counter moves forward. The pseudo code should appear like this:

```py
for i in range(N):
    A=object_creator(a,b,c[i])
    some_array[i]=A.some_function()
```

Should I include a `del A` command in the loop for memory preservation or since its reference is reused, is the memory deallocated?

Apologies if it is a duplicate question.

Comment: No need - it will be automatically overwritten

Comment: The answer to "should I use del?" is almost always "no".

Comment: Python uses an internal garbage collector: memory used by unreferenced objects is reclaimed automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by "creating objects recursively"? I see no recusrion in the given (and btw incomplete) code snippet

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I will edit it. It should "in a loop" rather than recursively. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, you don't need to include `del A`. For a full explanation, I recommend you have a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/garbage-collection-python/

From the first paragraph:

> Python’s memory allocation and deallocation method is automatic. The user does not have to preallocate or deallocate memory similar to using dynamic memory allocation in languages such as C or C++.

This is Python's internal garbage collection - it will clean up the memory of unreferenced object automatically. As a general rule, try and avoid using `del` whenever possible.